# BackgroundWorker hide form window upon completion

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm having some trouble with hiding a form when a BackgroundWorker process is completed.

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    processing f2 = new processing();
    f2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // loop through and upload our sound bits
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\wav", "*.wav", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string soundBit in files)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
        byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://mywebsite.com/upload.php", "POST", soundBit);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    formSubmitted f3 = new formSubmitted();
    f3.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    f3.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Basically, after the 'submit' button is pressed, the application begins to upload the files to the webserver via a php script. Once the upload is complete, the RunWorkerCompleted method is triggered, opening the `formSubmitted` form. The issue I'm having is that the `processing` form does not close once the backgroundworker is complete and the `formSubmitted` opens directly on top of the `processing` form - as opposed to what I want, having the `processing` form close and then open the `formSubmitted` form.

Comment: What is the class containing all the methods above (which the `this` references to)?

Comment: The class is `uploadPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you are never closing `processing` form:

try following:

```
private processing _processingForm;

private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _processingForm = new processing();
    _processingForm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    _processingForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    _processingForm.Show();

    this.Hide(); //HIDES THE CURRENT FORM CONTAINING SUBMIT BUTTON

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Now on completion hide `processing` form:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    formSubmitted f3 = new formSubmitted();
    f3.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

    _processingForm.Close();//CLOSE processing FORM

    f3.Show();

    this.Hide();//this REFERS TO THE FORM CONTAINING WORKER OBJECT
}
```

Comment: As the OP commented, `this` is always the `uploadPanel` (may be type of `Panel`).

Comment: Okay, now I see where I went wrong. Your code suggestion works as it should. Thanks for your help.